# 2019 Stack Overflow Developer Survey - Save Progress

Tags: feature-request, survey

While I'm happy to contribute to the [2019 Stack Overflow Developer Survey](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_1RGiufc1FCJcL6B), I'd prefer to complete the survey in parts.
Is there any plans to include a *Save Survey Progress* feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The third-party software provider we use for the survey (Qualtrics) provides automatic support for partial completion and coming back to the survey later. You have 1 week from your last activity to return and complete the survey, or else it starts you at the beginning.

This feature is also part of why our survey does not work well with certain ad blockers and security software. To avoid error messages that prevent you from taking the survey, please try specifically unblocking Qualtrics in your plugin or pausing the plugin while you take the survey.